# how to provide dynamic String such as ( server response ) in module?

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, androidinjector

i recently used from **New Android Injector with Dagger 2** in my project and i have an issue : 
i want provide a dynamic String with dagger and i don't know how do this; 
i receive a token from server and need to pass this as field  to and instance of **OkHttp3CookieHelper**;
how should i do this ?

i tried to pass this String into Module Constructor but i think this is not true!
i think maybe should use from @BindsInstance !!
please help ;)

this is my AppModule :

```
@Module(subcomponents = {MainActivityComponent.class})
    public class AppModule {

    private String cookie ;

    public AppModule(String Cookie){
        this.cookie = Cookie;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Context provideContext(Application application) {
        return application;
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OkHttp3CookieHelper provideCookie(@Named("baseURL") String baseURL,
                                      @Named("csrfToken") String csrfToken) {
        OkHttp3CookieHelper cookieHelper = new OkHttp3CookieHelper();
        cookieHelper.setCookie(baseURL, csrfToken, cookie);
        return cookieHelper;
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttp(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor,
                                       OkHttp3CookieHelper cookieHelper) {
        final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        httpClient.connectTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.readTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.callTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        httpClient.cookieJar(cookieHelper.cookieJar());
        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
        return httpClient;
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    HttpLoggingInterceptor provideHttpInterceptor() {
        final HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        return interceptor;
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    GsonConverterFactory provideGsonConverterFactory() {
        return GsonConverterFactory.create();
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("baseURL")
    String provideBaseURL() {
        return Const.BASE_URL;
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    @Named("csrfToken")
    String provideCrfToken() {
        return Const.CRF_TOKEN;
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Api provideApi(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(Api.class);
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(GsonConverterFactory converterFactory, OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient,
                             @Named("baseURL") String baseURL) {
        return new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseURL)
                                     .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                                     .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                                     .client(httpClient.build())
                                     .build();
    }
    @Singleton
    @Provides
    SharedPreferences provideSharedPreference(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences("myShp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    //and this is my AppComponent : 

       @Singleton
       @Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class, AppModule.class, 
                 ViewModelFactoryModule.class})
       public interface AppComponent {
         @Component.Builder
         interface Builder {
         @BindsInstance
         Builder application(Application application);
         AppComponent build();
         }

      void inject(App app);
}
```

issue : 
[dagger could not create instance from AppModule !](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOhRY.png)

Comment: Assisted inject should do the trick [see this](https://proandroiddev.com/brave-new-android-world-with-assistedinject-d11bdc20147d)

Comment: nobody can't help ? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally and after about 10 hours searching and read some articles i solved my issue:D

> NOTICE !

no need to pass your response token by yourself also no need to bind dependency(in this case response token)into AppComponent but if u want to do this u can use @Component.Builder or @Component.Factory that u can use this useful article :
[Dagger2: @Component.Factory and @SubComponent.Factory](https://android.jlelse.eu/dagger2-component-factory-and-subcomponent-factory-b181ec96b213)

### But to solve issue:

first should add this dependency to app.gradle file :

```
implementation 'com.github.franmontiel:PersistentCookieJar:v1.0.1'
```

then provide instance of **PersistentCookieJar** in appMoule class and
pass to our **OkHttpClient** instance:

```
@Singleton
@Provides
PersistentCookieJar ProvideCookieJar(Context context) {
    return new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(),
                                   new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));
}

@Singleton
@Provides
OkHttpClient.Builder provideOkHttp(HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor,
                                   PersistentCookieJar persistentCookieJar) {
    final OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    httpClient.connectTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.readTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.callTimeout(8, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    httpClient.cookieJar(persistentCookieJar);
    httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    return httpClient;
}
```

don't forget to provide Context that need to create PersistentCookieJar  instance :

```
@Provides
@Singleton
Context provideContext(Application application) {
    return application;
}
```

and in your Appication class should bind your application class :

```
DaggerAppComponent.builder()
                      .application(this)
                      .build()
                      .inject(this);
```

and your AppComponent Shoud be like this :

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidInjectionModule.class, ActivityBuilder.class, 
                      AppModule.class, ViewModelFactoryModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
   @Component.Builder
   interface Builder {
      @BindsInstance
      Builder application(Application application);
      AppComponent build();
   }
 
  void inject(App app);
}
```

OK every thing Done !
now your request contain cookie
and successfully can get server Response :)